# sonarquebe asks me Reduce the total number of break and continue statements in this loop to use at most one

Tags: java, sonarqube

Where it asks me to do it is in the second for, and that's where I have the most continues and breaks. Can someone give me an idea of ​​how to solve this issue? I'm really new to sonar and I have no experience in sonar corrections.

```
        public void validateV(String date, List<DataCustomersHV> dataCustomersHVList) throws IOException  {
        
        logger.info("Obteniendo lista ejecutivos enroladores.... ");
        long limit = Long.parseLong(ConstantsFiles.LIMIT);
        double scoreAuthenticationHV = Double.parseDouble(PropertiesCache.getInstance().getProperty("SCORE_AUTHENTICATION_HV"));
        List<String> notSendLynxs = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> codesEnrollmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<DataGenerateFiles> dataGenerateFilesList = null;
        GenerateFilePE generateFile = null;
        
        logger.info("Iniciando proceso 1 : N ..... ");
        QueriesVV executeQuery = new QueriesVV();
        List<DataCustomersME> dataCustomersMEList = executeQuery.getDataCustomersME();
        logger.info("Total de ejecutivos: " + dataCustomersMEList.size());
        int delivery = dataCustomersMEList.size() / 1000 + 1;
        for (DataCustomersHV dataCustomersHV : dataCustomersHVList) {
            int asOf = 0;
            int cdScore = 0;
            boolean enrollment = true;
            boolean serviceError = true;
            
            for (int i = 1; i <= delivery; i++) {  
                List<DataCustomersME> credentialListMil = getDataCustomersME(limit, dataCustomersMEList, asOf);
                
                DataValidServiceDaskpeak resp = null;
                logger.info("Validando cliente: " + dataCustomersHV.getCdUsuario());
                resp = restDaskpeak.getService((List<DataCustomersME>) credentialListMil, dataCustomersHV.getTxCredencialReference());
                if(resp.isTrue()) {
                    cdScore = (int) (resp.getScore() * 1000);
                    logger.info("cdScore: " + cdScore);
                    if (resp.getScore() >= scoreAuthenticationHV) {
                        enrollment = validaScore(executeQuery, dataCustomersHV, cdScore);
                        break;
                    } 
                }else {
                    serviceError = resp.isTrue();
                    break;
                }
                
                asOf++;
            }

            validaEnrollment(notSendLynxs, executeQuery, dataCustomersHV, cdScore, enrollment, serviceError);
            
            codesEnrollmentList.add(dataCustomersHV.getCdEnrolamiento());
            
        }
        logger.info("... Proceso de validacion 1 : N terminada ");
        
        logger.info("Obteniendo datos complementarios para notificaciones");
        dataGenerateFilesList = executeQuery.getDataGenerateFiles(CodesEnrollment.codesEnrollment(codesEnrollmentList));
        logger.info("Total de clientes: " + dataGenerateFilesList);
         
        validaLynxs(notSendLynxs, dataGenerateFilesList);
        generateFile = new GenerateFilePE();
        generateFile.generateFile(date, dataGenerateFilesList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When SonarQube complains about multiple breaks it generally wants you to reformat the code so that the **breaks** are not needed.

In this example it seems like we can change it so that we can only have a single **break** in the end.
We do that by checking for if your **resp.isTrue()** is null and then call **continue** instead if it is. This will remove one **break** and keep Sonar happy.

If there's no way your **resp.isTrue()** can ever be null than you can remove that **if** block and just add the **break** statement in the end as I did. But I think **null** is a valid value in this case.

```
for (DataCustomersHV dataCustomersHV : dataCustomersHVList) {
    int asOf = 0;
    int cdScore = 0;
    boolean enrollment = true;
    boolean serviceError = true;
        
    for (int i = 1; i <= delivery; i++) {  
        List<DataCustomersME> credentialListMil = getDataCustomersME(limit, dataCustomersMEList, asOf);
            
        DataValidServiceDaskpeak resp = null;
        logger.info("Validando cliente: " + dataCustomersHV.getCdUsuario());
        resp = restDaskpeak.getService((List<DataCustomersME>) credentialListMil, dataCustomersHV.getTxCredencialReference());

        // This should really be formatted to look nicer but you get the idea                
        if(resp.isTrue() == null) { 
            asOf++;
            continue;
        }

        if(resp.isTrue()) {
            cdScore = (int) (resp.getScore() * 1000);
            logger.info("cdScore: " + cdScore);
            if (resp.getScore() >= scoreAuthenticationHV) {
                enrollment = validaScore(executeQuery, dataCustomersHV, cdScore);
            } 
        } else {
            serviceError = resp.isTrue();
        }

        // If we reach this stage we should break the loop
        break;
    }

    validaEnrollment(notSendLynxs, executeQuery, dataCustomersHV, cdScore, enrollment, serviceError);
    codesEnrollmentList.add(dataCustomersHV.getCdEnrolamiento());
}
```

**EDIT**

Since it seems like the **resp.isTrue()** is a primitive value then the following code snippet is better.
Notice here that we removed the inner loop. This is because the **break;** statements never allowed it to iterate more than once so it's not needed.

```
for (DataCustomersHV dataCustomersHV : dataCustomersHVList) {
    int asOf = 0; // <-- this value will be updated but never used after the first iteration, can be replaced with inlince value
    int cdScore = 0;
    boolean enrollment = true;
    boolean serviceError = true;
        
    List<DataCustomersME> credentialListMil = getDataCustomersME(limit, dataCustomersMEList, 0 /*replaces asOf*/);
            
    DataValidServiceDaskpeak resp = null;
    logger.info("Validando cliente: " + dataCustomersHV.getCdUsuario());
    resp = restDaskpeak.getService((List<DataCustomersME>) credentialListMil, dataCustomersHV.getTxCredencialReference());

    // since resp.isTrue() is a primitive value this if/else covers all possible options
    if(resp.isTrue()) {
        cdScore = (int) (resp.getScore() * 1000);
        logger.info("cdScore: " + cdScore);
        if (resp.getScore() >= scoreAuthenticationHV) {
            enrollment = validaScore(executeQuery, dataCustomersHV, cdScore);
        } 
    } 

    serviceError = resp.isTrue(); // Value is always the same as resp.isTrue() so we can remove the else section

    validaEnrollment(notSendLynxs, executeQuery, dataCustomersHV, cdScore, enrollment, serviceError);
    codesEnrollmentList.add(dataCustomersHV.getCdEnrolamiento());
}
```

Comment: Brenin I don't know if this cycle works, in fact I think it marks an error if(resp.isTrue() == null) {, I just tried it and if it shows an error, it tells me that, "the operdor == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, null"

Comment: @JonathanOrtiz that means that it's not possible for the value to be null. It's most likely a primitive value. I'll update my answer for this scenario

Comment: Brenin It is that according to me you cannot compare a boolean expression with a null, because it is true or false, but null, it will not let me

Comment: @JonathanOrtiz A primitive boolean can never be null, that's why the compiler is complaining. If you try to initialize a boolean without giving it a value it will default to false

Comment: Brenin Since it seems like the resp.isTrue() is a primitive value then the following code snippet is better. Notice here that we removed the inner loop. This is because the break; statements never allowed it to iterate more than once so it's not needed.

Comment: Brenin Edit my question, and you know why I can't remove the second for loop

Comment: Then generally what you need to do in situations like this is to extract some of the calcutations. Tbh there's a lot going on in your method and you might be better suited to change your logic so that the break statements are not needed at all. For instance, maybe you can validate the score inside the resp class and then just return the proper boolean to indicate if there's an error

Comment: Brenin Honestly, I don't know how to attack it, everything is fine, the only problem is what is inside the second for loop

Comment: @JonathanOrtiz It's perfectly fine, generally it's flagged by Sonar because it has the potential to hide bugs because it's an indicator that too much is happening in the same place